# Convert hexane to 1,6-dibromohexane

Tags: organic-chemistry, halides, hydrocarbons

Is it possible by any means or by using some reagents to convert 
hexane to 1,6-dibromohexane? The yield should also be good.

Comment: In case you need 1,6 disubstituted hexane, consider either a dirt cheap adipic acid as a starting material or coupling of two $\ce{C3}$ fragments, porduced from allilic derivatives.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In principle, alkanes may be converted to alkyl bromides by photoinitiated bromination.

However, taking statistics (2 $\ce{CH3}$ vs 4 $\ce{CH2}$ groups) and stabilities of the radicals resulting from H abstraction by a bromine radical from your starting material into account, this approach is pretty worthless and will most likely yield 1,6-dibromohexane as a minor product in a complex mixture.

Consequently, your reasonable options are a) a different starting material (and a different synthesis) or b) simply buy 1,6-dibromohexane (around 20 Euro for 100 g).